# Need example of dojo scatter or bubble chart

Tags: dojo

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to tackle the scatter and bubble chart in dojo. Does anyone have an example or good documentation I can look at to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unlike any other chart (line,bar,area which takes two inputs per point , x and y)

**bubble chart takes three inputs per point ( x, y , and size of bubble)**

Bubble Chart Example:

```
            require([
              "dojox/charting/Chart",
              "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
              "dojox/charting/plot2d/Bubble",
              "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
              "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
              "dojo/domReady!"
            ],function(Chart,theme){
             var d1 = [];
             for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1){
                d1.push({x: i, y: parseInt(Math.random() * 30), size: parseInt(Math.random() * 10)});
                 // or you can put "size:1" for simplicity
             }
             var chart = new Chart("container");
             chart.addPlot("default", {
                 type:"Bubble"
             });
             chart.addAxis("x");
             chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"});

             // Add the series of data
             chart.addSeries("Demo", d1);
             chart.render();
            });
```

**Scattered charts are similar to any other point chart except the x axis values can be in float (or double) type.**

Scattered Chart Example :

```
            require([
              "dojox/charting/Chart",
              "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
              "dojox/charting/plot2d/Scatter",
              "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
              "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
              "dojo/domReady!"
            ],function(Chart,theme){
              var d1 = [];
              for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i += 0.1){
                  d1.push({x: i, y: parseInt(Math.random() * 30)});
              }
              var chart = new Chart("container");
              chart.addPlot("default", {
                 type:"Scatter"
              });
              chart.addAxis("x");
              chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"});

              // Add the series of data
              chart.addSeries("Demo", d1);
              chart.render();
            });
```

Hope this helps ...  ..

Comment: Much better than dojotoolkit, feel like doing the whole package ;) jk.