# Label the bubbles in a dojo chart

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo

I'd like a descriptive label next to or inside my dojox charting bubbles.  I can't see in the documentation how it is done.

Js Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/martlark/ErNEM/

And here is some sample code from stack over flow question: [Need example of dojo scatter or bubble chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571737/need-example-of-dojo-scatter-or-bubble-chart)

```
require([
          "dojox/charting/Chart",
          "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
          "dojox/charting/plot2d/Bubble",
          "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
          "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
          "dojo/domReady!"
        ],function(Chart,theme){
         var d1 = [];
         for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1){
            d1.push({x: i, y: parseInt(Math.random() * 50), size: parseInt(Math.random() * 10)});
             // or you can put "size:1" for simplicity
         }
         var chart = new Chart("container");
         chart.addPlot("default", {
             type:"Bubble"
         });
         chart.addAxis("x");
         chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"});

         // Add the series of data
         chart.addSeries("Demo", d1);
         chart.render();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be an option called text.  but it seems that they did not include this is the bubble element.  What you can do is have a tooltip that will show when the user mouses over the circle.

```
 new Tooltip(chart,"default);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/kpy3B/1/

Comment: I do have that enabled in my production code, but I'd much rather there be permanent labels on the bubbles.